# Issue with Zurb Foundation anchors in heading tags on Android Froyo

Tags: anchor, zurb-foundation, android-2.2-froyo

On Android Froyo (Galaxy S phone) default browser, the issue I'm seeing is when I tap on a link that is in a h1 or h2 or any heading tag, the active link box appears above the link. In some cases the box doesn't appear at all and the link doesn't work. It appears to only be links in heading tags. I've also tested it on iPhone 4s and Android Jellybean, and they work fine. I've narrowed it down to something inside foundation.css, but I can't find the CSS that's doing it or if it's a "feature" of Froyo browser.

Has anyone else seen this? Is there a fix?

TIA,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem. In foundation.css (Foundation 4) text-rendering: optimizeLegibility. It may be related to WebKit bug 41363.
I nullified that node and things are back to normal.